# Create a table and alternate colors for cells

Tags: flutter

i'm new to Flutter and i want to create a table using only Column an Row widgets.
i'm not supposed to know about gridview or other widgets.
also, i should alternate background colors (two colors) for each cell and begin each row with a different
color than the precedent one.
an image  to clarify the needed layout
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBR6E.png)

A function could be ideal to prevent repeating the same code.
How to proceed please.

didn't tried any code yet, i need guidance

Edit:
i have managed to forge some dirty code that shows the needed result, any improvements ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
Color getMyColor(int c, int r) {
  if (c % 2 == r % 2) {
    return Colors.yellow;
  }
  return Colors.black;
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: const Text('CheckerBoard')),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++)
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (var y = 1; y <= 5; y++)
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          color: getMyColor(x, y),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

Comment: No, simply nested rows and columns like in a checkerboard layout

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckerBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckerBoardState createState() => _CheckerBoardState();
}

class _CheckerBoardState extends State<CheckerBoard> {
  final List<Square> squares = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        squares.add(new Square(x: x, y: y));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        crossAxisCount: 8,
        children: squares);
  }
}

class Square extends StatelessWidget {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  Color? getColor() {
    if (x % 2 == y % 2) {
      return Colors.yellow;
    }
    return Colors.black;
  }

  const Square({Key? key, required this.x, required this.y}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: getColor(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ittanta Technologies , but i have to stick with nested rows and columns only.
i have forged together a solution that needed to be improved.
'''